# DriveApp.getFolderById Permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to "upgrade" an old script from **DocsList** to **DriveApp** and having a problem with a **getFolderById** call. The script had worked previously using **DocsList.getFolder**. I have a (previously-created) folder named "Email Archive" that I'm trying to access in script. Through using Logs and Execution Transcript, I've verified that I'm correctly passing the string "Email Archive" in the baseFolder parameter to the following statement:

> var baseFolderObject = DriveApp.getFolderById(baseFolder);

When that statement is executed, I get the following error:

> Execution failed: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do
>   not have permission to access it.

The "Email Archive" folder was created previously by the same script with a script call to **docsList.CreateFolder**, and no permissions were specified.

Do I need to do something to change the folder permissions to allow my script to access it now that I'm using **DriveApp** instead of **DocsList**? Do I need to create a new folder using **DriveApp** and specify permissions, and if so what permissions do I set to allow my script to access the folder and create subfolders and files without allowing it to be visible to the entire Internet?

Thanks in advance for any help,

~ Jim Fennell

Comment: if you haven't done so, be sure and run the code from the code editor at least one time where it should ask for needed permissions to be granted

Comment: @ScampMichael, Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried creating a new copy of the sheet, which DID prompt me for permissions, but when I allowed it, I still got the error.I'm even getting the error with this, which makes me suspect I'm writing something wrong:

`DriveApp.createFolder("EmailArchive");`
`var baseFolderObject=DriveApp.getFolderById("EmailArchive");`

Not much there and I still get: Execution failed: No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.

Comment: ID is not name. DriveApp.getFolderById("EmailArchive");  check the docs and see @Spencer Eastons's answer

Comment: @ScampMichael, Thanks again - that is what I was doing wrong. Apologies for not providing the full detail at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DriveApp you can get a folder by ID or by name. You are passing the name to the getFolderById() method. Try this below:

```
var myFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(baseFolder).next();
```

The getFoldersByName returns an iterator that has the standard hasNext()/next() syntax that iterators carry.  The code above saves the first folder returned with the name provided in 'baseFolder' to the myFile variable. Remember that in drive multiple folders can have the same name, hence returning an iterator vs a single folder.

Comment: I figured it was something simple like that - not sure why I didn't see it. I'll give that a try, but it definitely sounds like it will work. Thanks!!! Update to follow...

Comment: This absolutely did the trick. Thanks so much. Credit to you as the first with the detail needed.

Comment: Answers are responses to questions. You need to read the question to get the context of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Email Archive").next();