# DriveApp.getFolderById results in "you do not have permission" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am having issues with the *getFolderById* function. I am the owner of the folder in question. The specific call is as follows.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('string_id_of_my_folder');
```

I am passing the long string of the ID of the folder inside the function. 
I ran the function inside the editor to make sure permissions have been turned on - and I'm not getting any errors.

But when I try to run the function inside the spreadsheet, I get the following error message: *"You do not have permission to call getFolderById"*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Simliar issue reported here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2905. Though the exact error is different, its possible that even in your case, the Drive Apps have been disabled in the domain. Are you using a google apps domain account? If so, try  the code on a personal account and see. edit: actually the fix may be easy. Check the same question and the answer to it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709811/driveapp-getfolderbyid-permissions

Comment: Suhay - I read the discussion on  stackoverflow.com/questions/30709811/.

Comment: Suhay - I read the discussion on  stackoverflow.com/questions/30709811/ -     and I am still stuck. (A) I tried the same code in my personal account  - of course, I changed the folder ID to the id of a folder whose owner is my personal email xxx@gmail.com. Getting same error message. (B) I also tried the method suggested in the posting above:   `var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("BlotterImprovements").next();` .... And still getting similar     _You do not have permission to call getFoldersByName_    error!

Comment: Found the answer. The call was inside a custom function where the script was  "return"ing a value to a cell. I took the return function out, and it now the function works.

Comment: Hi. Same issue here but not solved with getFolderByName("foldername").next(). Inside editor works, in sheet no! Still get permission error. Permissions checked and deleted/created again but still error!

Answer (score 6):

Without setting the OAuth scopes you get something like below...
[image]

So the specific answer to this is you need to set OAuth scopes with this

`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"`

in the appscript.json file. To find view this file you need to go to the settings of the App Script project.
[image]

Whenever you're using any of the Google API's you need to add the scopes from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes). This will then ask you again for permission by logging into your account.

```
{
 "timeZone": "Europe/London",
 "dependencies": {
  "enabledAdvancedServices": [
   {
    "userSymbol": "Classroom",
    "version": "v1",
    "serviceId": "classroom"
   }
  ]
 },
 "oauthScopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
 ],
 "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
 "runtimeVersion": "V8",
 "webapp": {
  "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
  "access": "MYSELF"
 }
}
```

You should now see something like this
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that custom functions & simple triggers run with limited permissions: you can't perform actions that require user credentials, like reading from another file. These limitations are spelled out [here for custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced) & [here for simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

Installable triggers don't have this limitation. So if you needed to access another when you open your current file or from a standalone script, you'll need to install an `Open` trigger. [Here's Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).